# Unable to execute loop sequentially

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run the following code.

The result I get is the `when` call is not executed if the control goes into the `if` condition inside the loop. Also I am unable to make ajax call in the second `if` condition during the last iteration.

How can I make this execute sequentially ?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < myBoxList.length; i++) {

        console.log('for loop: '+i);

        if (myBoxList[i].isChecked == true) {

            checkedProjectList.push(myBoxList[i]);
            console.log('Inside When : '+i);

            $.when(generateXMLforSelectedProject(myBoxList[i])).then(function (XML) {

                ProjectDataXML += XML;
                console.log('Inside When : '+i);
                if (i == myBoxList.length - 1) {
                   // execution complete
                   // perform ajax call
                }


            });

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it happens because you are using a loop and async calls, so the loop does not wait for the ajax responses. You have to change the logic. See this example that I made with your code:

```
var Program = {

    Init: function(){
        this.Elems = myBoxList;
        this.CheckedProjectList = [];
        this.Counter = 0;
        this.DoJob();
    },

    DoJob: function(){
        if( this.Counter == this.Elems.length ) return;

        if( !this.Elems[this.Counter].isChecked ){
            this.Counter++;
            this.DoJob();
            return;
        }

        this.CheckedProjectList.push(this.Elems[this.Counter]);
        console.log('Inside When : ' + this.Counter);

        $.when(generateXMLforSelectedProject(myBoxList[i])).then(function (XML) {

            ProjectDataXML += XML;
            console.log('Inside When : '+i);
            if (Program.Counter == Program.Elems.length) {
                // execution complete
                // perform ajax call

                // when ajax succeeds....
                Program.Counter++;
                Program.DoJob();
            }

        });
    }

};

$(function(){
    Program.Init();
});
```

I know it looks a little different than your code but I think it's also clear and readable.

The logic is: You have to wait for async response before call a new one. So a loop here is not valid. You need to have a method which calls itself when needed (recursive).

This is an example wrote on the fly, so it's possible that you have to make changes to make it work properly.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I used recursive function using your advice. Really made things much simpler :)

Comment: I'm glad if it helped you  Please, consider to mark answer as valid if it solved your issue to help others to find solutions for their own issues.